# how I should compare my data to an array json

Tags: php, arrays, json

> I'm having a hard time in comparing day to array
>
> this is my array:

```
array:2 [
0 => {
  "id": 1
  "time_in": "08:00:00"
  "time_out": "17:00:00"
  "days": "["tuesday","thursday","saturday"]"
}
1 => {
  "id": 2
  "time_in": "09:00:00"
  "time_out": "18:00:00"
  "days": "["monday","wednesday","friday"]"
}
  ]
```

> note: days are json data from database
>
> and I have this variable day

```
$day = 'friday';
```

> I just want to get the array data with 'friday' in their days
>   please help me on my code I just don't know how I should manipulate it
>   or what code I will use to get it

---

I expect to have this output:

```
$day = 'friday';

1 => {
      "id": 2
      "time_in": "09:00:00"
      "time_out": "18:00:00"
      "days": "["monday","wednesday","friday"]"
    }
```

> because it has friday in its day

Comment: `array_walk_recursive` - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php and `in_array` - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Please, Consider minimal [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because nobody will code for you, this is advice site, not free programmes. Show more effort in finding solution - for example, you current code, after update.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **in_array()** function, which searches an array for a specific value.

for search **$day="friday"**, i declare another array as **$b** and put filtering value into it.

Try this:

```
$array = array(array("id"=>"1","time_in"=>"08:00:00","time_out"=>"17:00:00","days"=>'["tuesday","thursday","saturday"]'),
array("id"=>"2","time_in"=>"09:00:00","time_out"=>"18:00:00","days"=>'["monday","wednesday","friday"]'));
      $day = "friday";
      $b = array();
      foreach ($array as $val) {
           if (in_array($day,$val['days'])) {
               $b[] = $val;
           }
       }

    print_r($b);
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation about why the OP should try this, what it does and how it solves the issue and not just "Try this".

Comment: it doesn't work, it says "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: maybe the problem is the json data needed to be decode first?

Comment: assign this value in $array. `$array = json_decode('[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "time_in": "08:00:00",
  "time_out": "17:00:00",
  "days": ["tuesday","thursday","saturday"]
},
 {
  "id": 2,
  "time_in": "09:00:00",
  "time_out": "18:00:00",
  "days": ["monday","wednesday","friday"]
}
  ]',true);

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I Update my answer as per your hint. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: but only the 'days' in the array are in json format

Comment: use this if condition: `if (in_array($day,json_decode($val['days'],true)))`

Answer (score 0):

use `in_array` to find data in array

```
foreach($your_array as $obj){
   if(in_array($day, $obj->days)){
      return $obj;
   }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, It says that "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: it still doesn't work, it says that "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given"

Comment: it is because `days` is a string `"["monday","wednesday","friday"]"` can you remove the two `"`?

Answer (score 0):

let's say that your JSON data is defined as `$json`:

```
$json_array = json_decode($json);

$result = [];

foreach($json_array as $arr){
    if(in_array($day,$arr->days)){
        $result[] = $arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// the day you want
$day = 'friday';

// decode json to php array
$days = json_decode($yourJSONArrayFromDatabase, true);

for ($i=0; $i < count($days); $i++)
{
    if (in_array($day, $days[$i]['days'])) {
        echo json_encode($days[$i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for ($i=0; $i > count($days); $i++)` this never runs.